# Split HTML files

Tags: php, html, css, file-io

How would I split a HTML formatted file into several HTML files (complete with with HTML, HEAD and BODY tags) with PHP? I would have a placeholder tag (something like `<div class='placeholder'></div>` ) for all the places I want to cut.

Thanks.

Comment: This basically seems to be reinventing the idea of templating...like with Smarty...is there a reason why this isn't an option?

Comment: Reinvention something isn't always bad. I reinvented my own template engine for my site and its superior in flexibility. However, I think you are probably right, in this situation, if the OP doesn't know how to do it, I think something like Smarty might be a better option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$sourceHTML = file_get_contents('sourcefile');

$splitContents = explode("<div class='placeholder'></div>", $sourceHTML);

foreach ($splitContents as $html) {
    // save html to file
}
```

Edit: whoops.  As user201140 correctly points out, I missed the fact that each html file has to be a valid document.  Since it's not specified exactly what the head tag should contain, I'll assume that the head tag of the combined document should be replicated to each copy.  In that case:

```
$sourceHTML = file_get_contents('sourcefile');
preg_match("/(^.*<body.*?>)(.*)(<\/body.*$)/is", $sourceHTML, &$matches);
$top = $matches[1];
$contents = $matches[2];
$bottom = $matches[3];
$splitContents = explode("<div class='placeholder'></div>", $contents);
foreach ($splitContents as $chunk) {
    $html = $top.$chunk.$bottom;
    // save html to file
}
```

Comment: What would happen to the HTML, HEAD BODY tags for each page? Each part needs to be a stand alone HTML file.

Comment: I assume you actually implemented the filesaving code?  If so, it's tough to know what the problem is.  Most likely the regex doesn't match, although I've tried it on a bunch of html files and it matches them all.  It certainly won't work if the source html doesn't have a body tag.

Answer (score 0):

The preg seems only to work for small files...

Anyway... To split an HTML file of this form :

```
(header...) <body><div class='container'> (intro...) 
<h3>Sect 1</h3> (section...) 
<h3>Sect 2</h3> (section...) 
(etc...) 
</div></body></html>
```

I manage this way :

```
$splitContents = explode("<h3", $sourceHTML);
$i=0;
$last=count($splitContents)-1;
foreach ($splitContents as $chunk) {
    if($i==0) {
        $beginning=explode("<body", $chunk);
        $top=$beginning[0];
        $html = $chunk ;
    } else {
        $html = $top . "<body><div class='container'><h3" . $chunk ;
    }
    if($i !=$last) $html .= "</div></body></html>";
    // save html to file
    ++$i;
}
```